# VBA Excel, mismatch for inputbox as integer

Tags: vba, excel

My code

```
Dim a As Integer
a = InputBox("Enter the number", "Program", "", 7000, 6000)
If a = Empty Then
    ' do code...
Else
    MsgBox "Enter the number."
End If
```

If I leave an empty field , Excel returns a `Type Mismatch` error. I would like to display a message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `a` is an `Integer`, it cannot contain a `String` or be `Empty`. Use a `Variant` and then check to see what has been returned:

```
Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Integer

a = InputBox("Enter the number", "Program", "", 7000, 6000)

If Not IsNumeric(a) Then
    'a is not a number
Else
    'a is a number and can be converted to Integer
    b = CInt(a)
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

You have `a` defined as `Integer`. `Integer` cannot be empty. Use `Variant` instead of `Integer`:

```
Dim a As Variant
a = InputBox("Enter the number", "Program", "", 7000, 6000)
If a = Empty Then
    ' do code...
Else
    MsgBox "Enter the number."
End If
```

Comment: +1 for first correct answer - although you do want `If IsEmpty(a) Then`

Comment: @brettdj why don't you post your own answer? :)

Comment: Because you already nailed the key part, and we already have a  repeat (close in time) of your answer. Why add another? :)

Comment: Thanks, but I can only enter a number.

Comment: @user2060848 what do you mean?

Comment: Code is to be executed only when I type a number. Not a text.

Comment: @OskarStrasburger if you want code to be executed when some text (non-numeric letters) typed, use `If IsNumeric(a) Then`

Comment: @OskarStrasburger that was new information that was not included in your initial question.