# Create an array for a specific amount inputfields in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an inputbox in excel to enter a certain amount of records. I manage to get code below working but I want the for loop to run for a specific amount of time (variable n).

```
Sub fillInArray()

// Dim n As Integer
// n = InputBox("Provide number")

Dim StudentName(1 To 5) As String

   For i = 1 To 5

    StudentName(i) = InputBox("Enter student Name")
    Cells(i, 1) = StudentName(i)
   Next

End Sub
```

Only when I adjust my code like this it doesn't work.

```
Sub fillInArray()

Dim n As Integer
n = InputBox("Provide number")

Dim StudentName(1 To n) As String

   For i = 1 To n

    StudentName(i) = InputBox("Enter student Name")
    Cells(i, 1) = StudentName(i)
   Next

End Sub
```

Anybody thoughts on what Im doing wrong?

Comment: [**`ReDim StudentName(1 To n) As String`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Comment: `Dim Students() As String` then `Redim Students(1 to n)`

Comment: Also, be careful with someone hitting cancel: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14809971/2258

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub fillInArray()
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    n = InputBox("Provide number")
    ReDim StudentName(1 To n) As String
       For i = 1 To n
            StudentName(i) = InputBox("Enter student Name")
            Cells(i, 1) = StudentName(i)
       Next
End Sub
```